# Combine stacks from similar threads into one entry

Tags: windbg

When analyzing stack traces with Windbg, I am using `~*e!clrstack`

It would be useful to have a way to report identical stacks only once, especially when the number of threads is large.
One option would be a small parser utility for the output, but this requires additional steps.

Is there some Windbg extension or command that could help?

Comment: Facing the the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For native code, you would use [`!uniqstack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display a stack trace for each thread with similar stack traces omitted.

I'm not sure that an equivalent managed extension command exists. Your best bet for an overview may be to use [`!EEStack -short -EE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to hide stacks that are not running managed code, holding a lock, or waiting on GC.

Depending on the problem you are looking at, one or the other (or maybe both) could help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simultaneously open the dump in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 and use the “parallel Stacks” window. Don’t know how good this works is for managed.